# Hibernate ManyToOne with @Formula

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

I have two database tables and would like to set up a many to one relationship between the two using Hibernate.

[image]

[image: AND]

I did not construct these two tables, but were already made when I started on the project. I am new to Hibernate and would like to make a ManyToOne relationship between the two tables.

This normally would be strait forward, but the link between the two tables, "Praxiscode" is not the primary key, and I would like to do something like

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PraxisIITest.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @Formula(value = "(SELECT praxis.ID FROM lstPraxis praxis where praxis.Praxiscode=Praxiscode and Testdate BETWEEN praxis.BeginDate AND praxis.EndDate)")
    private PraxisIITest praxisIITest;
```

but when specifying the @Formula described above it throws an exception complaining that a column is not in 'field list'

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'praxisiite1_.praxisIITest_ID' in 'field list'
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
```

Here is where ID is specified in PraxisIITest ->

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lstPraxis")
@Cache(region="edu.uky.cepis.cache.praxisIItest", usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class PraxisIITest implements java.util.Comparator<PraxisIITest>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;
```

Am I going about this all wrong? or am I missing something very basic, My understanding is this should work...

Any thoughts or advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Nothing is jumping out by staring at this...What *should* help is tracing/logging the generated (by Hibernate) SQL.

Comment: What database platform are you using? Typically, there are database diagnostic tools that you could use (i.e. MySQL Query Log, or MS SQL Server Profiler) to see what Hibernate is doing behind the scenes...

Comment: I set logging level to trace and do not see anything obvious yet...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: I have enabled logging and after watching the mysql logs and what hibernate is doing "behind the scenes" I still can not seem to track down the problem.... , When I add an `@JoinColumn(name = "PRAXISCODE")` it no longer throws an error, but simply does not get PraxisIITest ( when debugging it is null after the mysql select statement)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you aren't using a valid SQL fragment; it assumes that Hibernate will do some aliasing:

```
(SELECT praxis.ID FROM lstPraxis praxis where praxis.Praxiscode=Praxiscode and Testdate BETWEEN praxis.BeginDate AND praxis.EndDate)
```

Testdate doesn't exist in lstPraxis table (according to your images), it is in the tbl20Praxis table.  Even if that table is what the PraxisIITest entity is mapped to, I think you need to explicitly do the table join in your @Formula fragment.

I didn't think that Hibernate did any processing of the formula, treating it as native SQL instead.  But that makes the error you're seeing all the more confusing...